# Prove $( p \land \lnot q ) \lor ( p \land q) \Leftrightarrow p$

Tags: logic

I'm trying to prove $( p \land \lnot q ) \lor ( p \land q) \Leftrightarrow p$

by doing the following:

$$\begin{align}
( p \lor p ) \land \lnot &q & Distributive \\
p \land \lnot &q & Idempotent \\
\end{align}$$

$q$ is still $\{T,F\}$, as is $\lnot q$. Therefore, $( p \land \lnot q ) \lor ( p \land q)$ is contingent upon both q and p.

But my book says it should reduce to p.

Does anyone out there have any insights?

Comment: You applied distributivity incorrectly! $(a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c) = a \wedge (b \vee c)$

Comment: @Lynn - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the correct distributive statement should be:$$p \land (\lnot q \lor q)$$ The final result should follow quite easily from this.

Answer (score 1):

As [Lynn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/141424/lynn) correctly pointed out, I applied the Distributive Law incorrectly. It should go:

$$\begin{align}
( p \land \lnot q ) &\lor ( p \land q ) \\
p \land ( \lnot q &\lor q ) &Distributive \\
p \land &T &Tautology \\
&p &Identity\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using distributivity we have :

$(p \wedge \lnot q) \vee (p \wedge q) \iff p \wedge (q \vee \lnot q)$

Since $(q \vee \lnot q)$ is always true this gives $p$.